# fortrabbit new apps and laravel artisan

Tags: php, laravel, fortrabbit

I just started a new L5.1 app wit fortrabbit new app features,but I couldn't find the way how can use artisan commands, in old apps I used ssh,but now it is not accesible. I need "php artisan migrate" and "php artisan db:seed " commands,how can I do without ssh access?

Comment: ehrm... get ssh access?

Comment: http://help.fortrabbit.com/old-and-new-apps#toc-only-git-no-ssh-sftp new fortrabbit feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new database configuration to `config/database.php`:

```php
// ..
'connections' => [
    // ..
    'mysql-tunnel' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'      => '13306',
        'database'  => 'my-app',
        'username'  => 'my-app',
        // don't save the password with your code
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
],
```

Then setup a [tunnel](http://help.fortrabbit.com/mysql#toc-terminal-tunnel-mysql):

```bash
$ ssh -N -L 13306:my-app.mysql.eu2.frbit.com:3306 tunnel@tunnel.eu2.frbit.com
```

Now you can run locally (in another terminal window):

```bash
$ DB_PASSWORD="your-password" php artisan migrate --database=mysql-tunnel
$ DB_PASSWORD="your-password" php artisan db:seed --database=mysql-tunnel
```

Comment: thank you,I got the logic. I made step 1 and step 2 without errors but when I write php artisan migrate --database=mysql-tunnel it says SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'

Comment: You are right. The env("DB_XX", "..") of course overwrote the actual values. I've updated the above answer. This should do the trick.

Comment: success,thanks a lot,but I think fortrabbit should make more documentation about these issues,it is great service